# Casperjs persisting cookies

Tags: cookies, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to use CasperJS for HTTP auth to an app then make a second request which if successful should trigger an XSS payload to send the cookies out. I know the auth works as the below code successfully triggers the XSS (I can see the outbound request), however no cookies are sent. I've found things like https://gist.github.com/alvises/6b159300a3f5f09de75f however I can't get anything to work so that cookies  are sent with the second request (urlAfterLoggedIn). Could anyone shed any light please?

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true, logLevel: 'debug'});

var urlBeforeLoggedIn = "http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/login.jsp";
var urlAfterLoggedIn = "http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx?edit=true&bookmarkID=2";

casper.start(urlBeforeLoggedIn)

casper.waitForSelector('form[method="post"]', function() {
  casper.fillSelectors('form[method="post"]', {
    'input[name="username"]': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'input[name="password"]': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }, true);
});

casper.thenOpen(urlAfterLoggedIn)

casper.run();
```